# Github workflow fails to build detox ios

Tags: react-native, expo, github-actions, detox

I am having issues with building a react native app(with expo- bare-work flow) in github actions using detox to run e2e tests. The issue seems to be when using the metro bundler the port is in use. It is failing on the following step "detox build -c ios". Are there any ports that cant be used on github actions? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated to resolve this issue :)

please see github action:

[image]

Below is my detoxrc.json:

[image]

Here is a copy of the error log:
[image]

Comment: It tells you the issue in the log. The connection for the packager has been refused. You should build a release flavor instead of debug.

Comment: Hey Leo I have tried this also and still no luck. Same issue. Had this issue a couple of times on my local and got around it by deleting .expo and .expo-shared. And then starting with expo start -c and then ctrl-c then running detox build. But unsure how I can replicate this behaviour for github action.

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with Expo and their environments.

Comment: You should always strive to create a standalone .app for testing. This must be possible with Expo. For example, before App Store release. Use the same method to create an app for testing.